# How can I use import and inheritance together?

Tags: java, netbeans

I have started learning Java and I tried to play with import and inheritance in netbeans IDE.

In netbeans I have created a project and two folders 'food' and 'food1'.

food has Fruit.java in it and food1 has Apple.java.

here's the code which is working fine.

Fruit.java

```
package food;
public abstract class Fruit{
}
```

Apple.java

```
package food1;
import food.Fruit;
class Apple extends Fruit{
}
```

Problem:
1. If i'm not declaring packages(package food and package food1) , it's not working. But i have already put them in the folders manually.
2. If i'm removing the import statement, it's not working. But the class fruit has been declared public.

Comment: Excellent story. What exactly is your question?

Comment: Your Problem descriptions are correct - means, it works as expected. The directory structure must be consistent with the package names, and if you want to use a class from a different package you must import it (or use a fully qualifed class name which includes the package name, like `... extends food.Fruit` - the usual approach is to import, though).

Comment: I have stated the 2 problem I am facing when I am doing some changes.@manu

Comment: None of your "problems" are real problems, you just don't understand (yet) how Java works. So you need to read a lot more tutorials and books about the basics, like http://www.studytonight.com/java/package-in-java.php

Comment: @AndreasFester you should probably post that as an answer.  Pretty much what I was going to say, but I don't want to just repeat your comment.

Comment: @JatinLalwani You seem to be saying everything works until you either remove the `package` lines or remove the `import`.  As others have said, that is correct behaviour.  Why would you want to remove them?

Comment: Because I wanted to know why removing them produces an error. I tried to find the answers on google but I didn't find any. And here people like manu trying to make fun of it. Anyway, I will search more and figure it out myself :). Thanks!

Comment: @JatinLalwani I'm not making fun of you. You simply did not ask a clear question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Problem descriptions are correct - means, it works as expected:

> 1. If i'm not declaring packages(`package food` and `package food1`) , it's not working

Yes, the directory structure must be consistent with the package names. If your directory structure looks like

```
src
 +--food
 |    +--Fruit.java
 +--food1
      +--Apple.java
```

then `Fruit.java` needs to have the `package food` statement and `Apple.java` needs to have the `package food1` statement.

> 2. If i'm removing the import statement, it's not working. But the class fruit has been declared public.

Yes, if you want to use a class from a different package you must import it (or use a fully qualified class name which includes the package name, like ... `extends food.Fruit` - the usual approach is to import, though). Declaring the class `public` is not sufficient - it just defines the class **can** be used from outside the package, but you still need to import it.

See also

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package
- http://www.studytonight.com/java/package-in-java.php

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for.. Thank you sir.